# Dynamically change element CSS properties after adding it on button click Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

After the user creates a div with a button click I'd like to be able to click on that div and change its color. I'm wondering why this is not possible. It works if the div is hard coded in but not after it is dynamically created. Also, how do I make it work?

```
$("#addDiv").click(function() {
    var div = '<div id="clickMe" style="width:200px; height:200px; background:blue;"></div>';
    $("#container").html(div);
});

$("#clickMe").click(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");   
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#clickMe', function(e){ ... })` is your friend, as googling for "javascript event delegation" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need event [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated element like following.

```
$('body').on('click', '#clickMe', function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");   
});
```

Comment: You need to listen on the `#clickMe` element ^^

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem. I've updated my answer. @moonwave99

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Just create listener right on the created element. Something like this:

```
$("#addDiv").click(function() {
    var $div = $('<div/>', {
        id: 'clickMe',
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
      })
      .css('background', 'blue')
      .click(function() {
          $(this).css("background", "red");   
      });
    $("#container").html($div);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhsvu2m8/)